# Is A New Object Instantiated Every Time This Loop Runs?

Tags: java

I was taking a Java test today and I got this weird question and I feel like I am right, but some of my classmates are saying another answer is right. There was a basic class, a default constructor that initialized the instances, and some methods. In the main class, there was some code like this (not exact because I do not remember it. Let's say the written class name was "tester."

```
public class Testing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 0;
        Tester t = new Tester ();
        Tester a;

        do {
            new Tester (); 
            x++;
        }while (x < 10);    
    }    
}
```

And the question was, how many objects are instantiated once the program is completely executed.

My logic was, there was one object instantiated outside the loop. Inside the loop, there was another object, but each time the loop ran, that one object just got re-instantiated. The loop didn't create a new object. So, I said only two objects would be have been instantiated after the program was done running, but some of my classmates said it was 11. Technically, what is correct?

Comment: It is 11. `new Tester()` creates a new object each time

Comment: The obvious answer is yes; but the real answer is maybe. If there are no side-effects to creating a `Tester` instance it's possible the compiler (or possibly the JIT) will work out that nothing happens with those instances and optimize the unreachable instances away.

Comment: *that one object just got re-instantiated.* There's no such thing. An object can only be instantiated once.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I understood that you have said it is a *possibility*. But do you have any proof/papers on this? (Just curious).

Comment: You can examine the actual byte-code with `javap -v` yourself; there *may* be a difference between compiling with `-O` (and without) and between Java revisions. No proofs/papers - and offsite resources are off-topic, and with a loop count of `10` there isn't practically time for JIT to replace anything here (today, AFAIK); but there are many more then 11 Objects created. The JVM allocates a lot of `String`(s) and other internal types - plus the `String[] args` is an Object. You could look with jvisualvm to see yourself.

Comment: Nice point @ElliottFrisch that the OP asked "How many objects are instantiated" but we all answered "How many `Tester` instances are created?" Interesting.

Answer (score 0):

The line `new Tester()` does several things

1. Allocates enough memory to store an instance of Tester
2. Calls the constructor (which sets up default values)
3. Returns a reference pointer to the new object, so you could assign it like you did for `t`

These steps were executed once for t and again for each loop execution, **a total of 11 times that a Tester was "instantiated." So your classmates were right.**

When the garbage collector runs, each instance of Tester will be deleted. The ones in the loop because they weren't saved in variables. The one stored in t can be deleted once the routine exits.

This is why you should be cautious when you invoke `new xyz()` for any class, especially in a loop. It is often expensive. Especially the allocation step. Of course it [is a tradeoff](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/149573/5065).

This is a great example of the computer doing exactly what you asked it to do. What you expected it to do was closer to:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x = 0;
    Tester t = new Tester();
    Tester a = new Tester();

    do
    {
        a.Reinitialise(); 
        x++;
    }

    while (x < 10);

}
```

Assuming here that you created a method `Reinitialise` inside `Tester`.

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/149563/should-we-avoid-object-creation-in-java

Comment: Interesting post shmosel. Added a link.

Answer (score 0):

To test this, you can have a static int counter declared in your Test class, and increment the count of the static counter in the constructor and print the value.

Check the value of the counter after this execution.

By the way.. it creates 11 objects.. give it a try.

Comment: Nice. One thing this does not confirm is how many times the allocator was called to allocate memory. It is possible (but unlikely?) that the same region of memory was reused.

Comment: @TomLeys But that wasn't the question.

Answer (score 0):

11 is the correct answer...whenever you call new, it will create and instantiate objects...

```
Tester a;
```

does not instantiate an object...it merely marks that objects assigned to this variable should be of tester type

Best to observe would be to write a print statement in the constructor and then just counting up the number of prints...